# How to create Layout for more that 14 inch screen in android?

Tags: android

I want to create a a app with multiple screen support for tablet as well as mobile view in landscape mode, how can i create diffrent layout for it, and android gives 7 to 10 inches xxhdpi mode, but my rang is 4 to 18.6 inch support screen app.

Comment: `xxxhdpi` is a screen *density*. It has nothing to do with screen *size*. Beyond that, [use `-wNNNdp` or `-swNNNdp` for your various screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers).

Comment: Ok thanks i will try it and give you a fast response, do you have any example on that?